# How to get the GLSurface Size?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

How can I get the Wisth and Height of the GLSurfaceView I am currently render in, in pixels?

Answer (score 0):

may be this:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {
```

}

of 
`public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer`